# Почему не подключается библиотека JSTL?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, jstl

Использую `Tomcat 10`, следовательно, согласно [информации](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) на официальном сайте могу использовать `Java 8`, но со следующими [изменениями](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi), а именно:

> Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*.

Ок, разобрались. Пытаюсь найти нужную ветку в репозитории `Maven`, чтобы подключить библиотеку `JSTL` и получаю вот такое (мы же ищем `jakarta`, верно?):

```html
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp/jakarta.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Ок, прописываю зависимость в `pom.xml`, открываю jsp-страницу, вставляю директиву `taglib` перед тегом `<html>` (мне нужна библиотека `core`, поэтому будет так):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

И моя IDE, которой выступает `Intellij IDEA`, выдает мне ошибку:

```
Cannot resolve taglib with uri http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
```

Хм. Открываем такой замечательный официальный сайт [jakarta.ee](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/1.2/tagdocs/c/tld-summary.html) и смотрим, каким должен быть `uri` и видим там такое замечательное чудо, которое и было написано у меня выше:

```
Standard Syntax:
     <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Но ошибки не возникает, если подключить `JSTL` библиотеку следующим образом:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

И теперь, при добавлении на jsp-страницу следующего кода (для попытки интернационализации):

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:setBundle basename="locale" />
```

выпадает ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
```

Тогда вопрос - в чем дело, собственно?

Comment: Если ошибки не возникает, то в чем проблема?

Comment: @RomanC, ошибка возникает, добавил в топике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С этими переименованиями `javax`, `jakarta`, `glassfish` черт ногу сломает. Хоть бы нормальную документацию составили.

В итоге то нужно вместо такой зависимости в `Maven`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

добавить такую:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Если это решило вашу проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте свой ответ как правильный.